# Code samples for Android Bluetooth programming

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm new to Android. I'm looking for some code samples for **Android Bluetooth programming**. Could you please post them for me? Any useful link would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried first to google it?

Comment: this is actually a very good question, as there is hardly any code out there and what there is doesn't work!

Answer (score 24):

I realize this is an old thread, but I thought I'd jot some notes. The Android Bluetooth example (already listed) has a bunch of issues (not the least of which is you need 2 Android devices to get it to function).

Take a look at the example at http://luugiathuy.com/2011/02/android-java-bluetooth/
where he is using BlueTooth on the Android device to hit a server (to do some robotics work).

Be aware of UUID issues (the way that BlueTooth decides what connection it can make is defined in the UUID), and check out 
http://www.avetana-gmbh.de/avetana-gmbh/produkte/doc/javax/bluetooth/UUID.html

Keep in mind that the 16 bits represented in the UUID (ie, `0x1101` for Serial Port) is misleading in that its really the least significant part and needs to be coded `0x00001101`.

Comment: thank you for posting this... it's so frustrating not knowing whether or not you are going about implementing bluetooth correctly, and even more frustrating trying to find some good code examples online. thanks for the information!

Answer (score 6):

Check out [android's tutorial for bluetooth](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html).

BTW, this is first result on google for [android bluetooth example](http://www.google.co.il/search?aq=0&oq=android%20bluetooth%20exa&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=android%20bluetooth%20example)

Answer (score 4):

check this example, it sends bipmap+text over 2 bluetooth android devices.

if you want the full project example and working download freely from:

http://letitbit.net/download/19347.172fecf1b1790bfbd64b4d2115a6/sendobject.rar.html

maybe this can help to all people with problems sending over bluetooth with Android...

Thanks to Pedro Fraca for his great help on this work.