# What is involved in connecting an app to a mac via Bluetooth?

Tags: android, air, bluetooth, unity-game-engine

I realize that this is the kind of question that frequently gets a lot of (well deserved) "what have you tried" comments and down-votes, but I'm hoping that by the time I'm done asking I can avoid that.

I've been looking around but unable to find the answer to how one goes about writing an application that consists of the following three things:

1. An Android app that connects to a host device via bluetooth
2. Communication io layer that sends signals back and forth on
   that bluetooth connection
3. A host resident native app (preferably Unity3D, or AIR) that can receive/send messages back and forth to the connected app.

I have written many Android applications so I am not in need of any kind of "getting started" hand-holding, rather I just need some guidance (preferably in the way of a web link or book tutorial) on what it takes to utilize bluetooth and how one actually communicates via it.

Thanks in advance for all useful tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few links that I found in terms of Bluetooth connections

First of all the dev guide(I assume you have already looked here, but if not this is a good place to start)

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html

This one is a basic tutorial on how to Bluetooth on android

- http://luugiathuy.com/2011/02/android-java-bluetooth/

This is a long PDF on Bluetooth programming in general (I haven't read it, but from what I have seen it looks over in depth) it covers java and OSX, but not android

- people.csail.mit.edu/rudolph/Teaching/Articles/BTBook.pdf

Here is a similar SO question which might contain helpful links

- [Code samples for Android Bluetooth programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619850/code-samples-for-android-bluetooth-programming)

This is the best Bluetooth open source project that I could find for android, it doesn't fit your description over well, but here it is anyways

- http://code.google.com/p/bluetooth-remote-control/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fpro%2Fapus%2Fblueremote

I realise that a lot of these links are simpler than what you really want, if I find anything more complicate I will add that.

Comment: Thanks, I'd seen a couple of these before but a couple are new... definitely a good place to start.  I'm having a harder time finding resources for the Host side of things than for the Client side of things (with Android being the client in that scenario).