# How to Transfer Files using Bluetooth in android and PC or another android device

Tags: android, java-me, bluetooth, uuid

I am trying to transfer file from PC to android phone and then vice versa or b/w to android phones but got stuck.

i know android programming at a expert level, i know the bluetooth API in android and in J2ME i know the bluetooth chat application but dont get exact idea to get from this. Please help me any code that works any Concept any idea that would help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of links, I don't know how much they will help you because you know programming very well, but here they are

This is a very nice PDF on Bluetooth from a programming perspective, it has a lot of detail on a range of different platforms(though sadly not android). You may find it very useful

- people.csail.mit.edu/rudolph/Teaching/Articles/BTBook.pdf

Here is another SO post asking about Bluetooth code

- [Code samples for Android Bluetooth programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619850/code-samples-for-android-bluetooth-programming)

Comment: Thanks bro for your help. but it was not for which i am looking for but very soon i will back to you when i solved the mistry

Comment: i done it. i created a Bluetooth Server for PC and an Android client to transfer files but first carefully go through the previous answer and then download the file and then read the Read Me first.txt file for installation instruction

[Download the project from here](https://rapidshare.com/files/3100729241/Read%20Me%20First.rar)

Comment: this link is now broken due to site's policy restrictions

Comment: Hi @NeerajSharma could you share me a code for transfer file between PC and android app?