# Android - Is it possible to read file from laptop using USB connection into application programmatically?

Tags: android, usb

I need to read a file from laptop using USB connection.

Is it possible to read from our application and use it?

I checked UsbManager class but does not have any sample code to do it.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Why don't you read it through wifi or bluetooth app ?

Comment: Usually Android device connected to computer is recognized as "Media device" or MTP. User can "send" file from computer to Android device. It is like sending something through the post office: receiver will only get what you sent him, but will not know what else you have in your possession.

Comment: @Chetan: Is it simple workaround to do with wifi or bluetooth? Because I do not have much time to develop life big module for this.

Comment: @Saravanakumar: yes it is really simple , there will be few apps available with some opensource code.

Comment: Look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387941/how-to-transfer-files-using-bluetooth-in-android-and-pc-or-another-android-devic

Comment: @izogfif: Do you have any sample code to do it?

Comment: http://digitalhacksblog.blogspot.in/2012/05/android-example-bluetooth-simple-spp.html

Comment: Thanks @Chetan. I will go through it and try it.

Comment: @Saravanakumar:Do I deserve vote up on any my answers

Comment: @Chetan: I think you need to create an answer, not a comment to get vote ups. I'm afraid that user with 29 reputation can't vote up comments.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to read from our application and use it?

No, sorry.

Comment: Ok. Then I will check using bluetooth or wifi. Thanks.

Comment: @CommonsWare how to send a file on computer from android device using USB ? i can i cheive this using command line `adb pull /sdcard/juned.jpg /root/juned/android_usb/` but how to do it programmatically [please check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615532/send-file-to-computer-system-using-usb)